# Interesting way to calculate volume of solid of revolution, is it a coincidence?

Tags: calculus, geometry

The question was:

> Find the volume $V$ obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y = 5x - x^2$ and $y = x^2-5x+8$ about the $y$-axis.

I first solved this problem using the shell method, and got an answer of $45\pi$. I wanted to try solving the problem in a different way, so I started by finding the area of the region bounded by the two curves. This area is 9:

[image]

Then, I noticed that if we find the circumference of the circle around the $y$-axis passing through the center of the region, and multiply it by the area of the region, we get the same answer as before. The center occurs at $x=2.5$, so the circumfrence of the circle is $5\pi$, and $$5\pi \cdot 9 = 45\pi\,.$$ Does this always work for problems like this, and if so, why?

Comment: It is known as "Pappus's centroid theorem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$V=\int_a^b 2\pi xf(x) dx=2\pi \int_a^b  f(x) dx\cdot \frac{\int_a^b  xf(x) dx}{\int_a^b  f(x) dx}=2\pi A x_G$$

which is known as [Pappus's Centroid Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html).

Comment: Interesting, but the proof seems too complicated. Why does it have to be the centroid and not any other point? Is there an intuitive explanation?

Comment: The expression $$\frac{\int_a^b  xf(x) dx}{\int_a^b  f(x) dx}$$ is by definition the x coordinate of the centroid, it cannot be any other point.

Answer (score 1):

Center of mass can be found as 
$$
x_C = \frac1{A}\int_A x\,dA
$$

When you multiply area to the circumference, you get:
$$
V = 2\pi x_C A = \int_A 2\pi x\,dA
$$

But $dV = 2\pi x\,dA$ is a volume of thin hoop. So basically the last integral is a method of hoops. (The shell is the stack of hoops in vertical direction). Thus, the method is legitimate.